# Google Sheets script to save a copy of a workbook to a new folder, and rename it to today's date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to using scripts so I'm in need of help. I'm using this code atm:

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A1:L8');
  sheet.setNamedRange('buildingNameAddress', range);
  var TestRange = sheet.getRangeByName('buildingNameAddress').getValues(); 
  Logger.log(TestRange); 
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy("'test'", destFolder); 
}
```

Obviously this just saves it as "test" but I'd like it to rename it to whatever the date is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const name = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Your Time Zone', 'yyyyMMdd');
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(name, destFolder);
```

Reference:

[formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)